# Protobuf-net skip deserialization of specific fields

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net

I have serialized this class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class TestClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public int[] hugeArray;
    [ProtoMember(2)] public int x;
    [ProtoMember(3)] public int y;
    //lot more fields and properties to serialize here...

}
```

How do I skip the [ProtoMember(1)] hugeArray during deserialization, so that only x, y, and other fields get deserialized?

My problem is that sometimes I quickly need only to get the 'metadata', which is what other fields and properties describe, but sometimes I need an entire object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

- two `RuntimeTypeModel` instances (one built manually with only the desired fields specified)
- two **types**; i.e. create a simpler `TestClass` that *simply omits the big fields* - i.e. `TestClassMetadata` - and deserialize into *that*; protobuf-net won't mind at all

Comment: My class has 30 fields and I tried to avoid duplicating code just to skip 1 field during deserialization. I wanted something like (pseudocode): RuntimeTypeModel.BuildModelFor(typeof(TestClass)).RemoveMember(1), but I don't thing there is anything similar offered by protobuf-net.

Comment: @Michal indeed - no Remove; would need TypeModel.Create(), Add(type, false) and then Add the members you *do* want