# It is possible to deserialize individual list items with protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, deserialization, protobuf-net

I have a some class with list:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<HugeSizeItem> Items;

    /* ... */

    [ProtoMember(999)]
    public SomeType Property999
}
```

and I need to deserialize specific list item, because if I deserialize all data this it takes a long time.

Comment: It's the same question as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444460/protobuf-net-skip-deserialization-of-specific-fields

Comment: @Master117 In question asked how to skip specific properties, but I need to get Items[index] without deserialization all list items

Comment: You have to deserialization all list items, how else are you going to know which entry is the correct one? Do you know that it's always number x in the list? If HugeSizeItem is too big you should change your data structure. You can skip all other properties.

Comment: @Master117 I found solution for me. I deserialize all data, but change HugeSizeItem to byte[] and add method for deserialization item by index from byte[] to HugeSizeItem. This is 10 times faster.